# How to get the coordinates of where a line and a circle intersect when the result gives an imaginary number?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

if you select a two points (everything in 2 dimensions), draw a circle centered on the first point and connect the two points with a line, and you know both of the point's coordinates and the radius of the circle, how do you get the coordinates of where the line and the circle intersect when the result is an imaginary number? sometimes when solving this problem the quadratic formula has a negative number on it's root which makes it impossible for me to know the coordinates of the point. anyone know how to solve this problem?

For Example. if you take the first point's coordinates (center of the circle) as (1,1), the second point's coordinates as (-2,2) and the radius of the circle as 1.
now if you use the equation for a circle ($r^2=(x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2$) and replace $y$ with the equation for the line ($y = mx+b$), we get the equation for the coordinate of the interception ($r^2=(x-x0)^2+(mx+b-y0)^2$).
we get $m$ by doing $\frac{y0-y1}{x0-x1}$ which in this case is $-\frac{1}{3}$. We get $b$ from $mx-y$ which in this case is $-\frac{4}{3}$. now if we put everything in the equasion, it should be like this: $1^2=(x-1)^2+(-\frac{1}{3}x-\frac{4}{3}-1)^2$
which I solve like this:
$1=(x-1)^2+(-\frac{1}{3}x-\frac{7}{3})^2$ $<=>$
$0=x^2-2x+1+\frac{1}{9}x^2+\frac{14}{9}x+\frac{49}{9}-1$ $<=>$
$\frac{10}{9}x^2-\frac{4}{9}x+\frac{49}{9}=0$ $<=>$
$x=\frac{-(-\frac{4}{9})\pm\sqrt{(-\frac{4}{9})^2-4\times(\frac{10}{9})\times(\frac{49}{9})}}{2\times(\frac{10}{9})}$ $<=>$
$x=\frac{\frac{4}{9}\pm\sqrt{-24}}{\frac{20}{9}}$

as you can see I can't calculate the X value of the interception because the $\sqrt{-24}$ gives a imaginary number.

Comment: What does "draw a circle on the first point" mean?  Is this a circle centered on the first point?

Comment: yes sorry for not specifying, the circle is centered on the first point! (first time posting, really frustrated with this problem, been searching for days and can't figure it out)

Comment: This is impossible.  We know the line joining the two points passes through a point in the interior of the circle, and it must pass through a point external to the circle, so it passes through a point on the circle, which we can find by algebra.  If you can give an example of the phenomenon, I'm sure we'll be able to point out your mistake.

Comment: To show your work, you'll need to show the formulas and equations you wrote. Here's a tutorial showing how to write them here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation (note that the examples include a quadratic equation and its solution). Make sure to edit all of this into the question rather than a comment.

Comment: imagine that the first point's coordinates are (1, 1) (basically the center of the circle), and the other point's coordinates are (-2, 2), the radius of the circle on the first point can be 1. now if we use the equation for a circle r^2=(x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2 and the equation for a line y = mx+b, the point where the line and the circle intersect should be r^2=(x-x0)^2+(mx+b-y0)^2. then we need to solve it for X, to get the X coordinate, but if we do, the result is an imaginary number. thank you for your patience btw :)

Comment: I suppose it took you more than two minutes to write that last comment, which is why you didn't see my admonitions to (1) use MathJax and (2) put all of it in the question, not a comment. But you can still fix that now. Actually I should have said (3) write **all** the equations you used (why do we always have to say this?), because your mistake is somewhere in the work you didn't show us. I don't get any imaginary numbers from your example.

Comment: done. took 30mins but hope it's worth it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple geometric approach to finding the intersection point. Call the point around which the circle is drawn $u$, call the other point $v$, and call the intersection point $x$. Because $x$ lies along the line connecting $u$ and $v$, the displacement between $x$ and $u$ must point along the same direction as the displacement between $v$ and $u$. Next, because $x$ lies on a circle of radius $R$ around $u$, the displacement between $x$ and $u$ must have length $R$. Hence the displacement between $x$ and $u$ is given by $R(v-u)/\|v-u\|_2$, and the intersection point is thus given by,

$$x = u + R\frac{v-u}{\|v-u\|_2}$$

Plugging in coordinates should give you your answer! For instance, take $R=1$, $u=(1,1)$, and $v=(-2,2)$. Then $v-u=(-3,1)$, and $\|v-u\|_2=\sqrt{9+1}=\sqrt{10}$. So the intersection point is,

$$x=(1,1) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}(-3,1)$$

Comment: so the solution in your example would be ~(0.05,0.68)? (this is rounded)

Comment: Yes. I believe you have the sign of $b$ wrong in your edited post (note that both points are above the x axis). With the correct sign your result should match mine.

Comment: Sorry, had a typo (now fixed). It should be (0.05,1.32).

Comment: ty! not only you gave a different solution to the problem (which I thought about but couldn't execute), but you also told me what was wrong with my current approach, I reviewed my math for 3 days and couldn't find it, you're totally right, the sign of b is wrong, it should be -b=mx-y. much love, ty for your help

Comment: no worries! happy I could help